# How to effectively map values of dictionary to df column?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a dictionary with states and zipcodes

```
states          zipcode

Sachsen         38440
Niedersachsen   20867
.
.
.
```

my dataframe has only zipcode, i tried following

```
df['states'] =  df.zipcode.map({item: k for k, v in temp.items() for item in v})
```

but this always doesnt work,it returns NaN.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `df['state'] = df['zipcode'].map(dict_map)`

Below is the dictionary structure I am using to perform operations, if your dictionary structure is different , you will have to make dict structure like below.

dict

```
dict_map = {'Sachsen': '38440', "Niedersachsen": '20867'}
#interchaging key value pair
dict_map = {value:key for key, value in dict_map.items()}
```

dataframe `df`

```
     zipcode
0    38440
1    20867
```

Complete code for creation of `dict` & `df` to mapping and creating new column in `df`.

Code-

```
dict_map = {'Sachsen': 38440, "Niedersachsen": 20867} #dict
dict_map = {value:key for key, value in dict_map.items()} #interchange key,value pair
dict_map.keys()
df = {'zipcode': [38440,20867]} 
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df)  #created one df
df['state'] = df['zipcode'].map(dict_map) 
df

Output

    zipcode state
0   38440   Sachsen
1   20867   Niedersachsen
```

ref link- https://datascientyst.com/pandas-map-column-dictionary/